# tree.DecisionTree.feature_importances_ Numbers correspond to how features?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 0)
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
importances = clf.feature_importances_
```

`importances` variable is an array consisting of numbers that represent the importance of the variables. I wonder what order is this? Is the order of variable `importances` is the same as `X_train`?

I am trying to make a plot from this. So order matters.

Comment: Yes, the order is the same as the order of the variables in `X_train`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take the column names from `X` and tie it up with the `feature_importances_` to understand them better. Here is an example -

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import pandas as pd

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
iris = load_iris()
iris_pd = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width'])
clf = clf.fit(iris_pd, iris.target)
```

I am taking the iris example, converting to a `pandas.DataFrame()` and fitting a simple `DecisionTreeClassifier`. Once the training is done, you can take the `columns` attribute of a pandas `df` and make a `dict` with the `feature_importances_` output.

```
print(dict(zip(iris_pd.columns, clf.feature_importances_)))
```

This will give you what you want -

```
{'sepal_length': 0.0, 'sepal_width': 0.013333333333333329, 'petal_length': 0.064055958132045052, 'petal_width': 0.92261070853462157}
```

Hope this helps!